# REST API implementation using Ulfius - URI definition

Tags: c, rest, http, uri

I am trying to test the Ulfius library for implementing REST API. My application is in C, so Ulfius made a right choice. I have little to no knowledge about how URI is formulated or HTTP works.
I compiled the simple_example.c file and while testing it, I get a seg fault when I do a POST with URL http://localhost:8537/test with key as name and value Arza (using postman app)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Ms6.jpg)
I know I am doing something wrong, please help.
This is the sample source file : https://github.com/babelouest/ulfius/blob/master/example_programs/simple_example/simple_example.c

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i have added the source file, and the image which shows the endpoints.

Comment: This seems a lot of effort to debug for someone, that's probably why you don't get any responses. Did you try to use valgrind to find the segfault yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what was the endpoint definition in these lines :
  ulfius_add_endpoint_by_val(&instance, "GET", PREFIX, "/multiple/:multiple/:multiple/:not_multiple", 0, &callback_all_test_foo, NULL);

Its working now, and I am not able to reproduce the segmentation fault now. Don't know what went wrong. Thanks hko (I cant tag you?)